# What must be added to nsswitch.conf to [Succes=return] for group database

Tags: glibc

Working on a CentOS machine, with GlibC 2.17 I am struggling to find a configuration which disables group lookup for local users on remote directories.

I know that be design the group lookup searches all directories but I thought adding `group: file [SUCCESS=return]` will resolve this.

But it seems, it doesn't :(

Then then I thought maybe `initgroups` can help but it doesn't seem to work `initgroups: files [SUCCESS=return] nis ldap`

My `nsswitch.conf`

```
passwd:     compat ldap
shadow:     files
group:      files nis ldap
hosts:      files dns nis
protocols:  files
rpc:        files
services:   files
initgroups: files [SUCCESS=return] nis ldap
```

This is the code snippet of glibc `internal_getgrouplist` function

```
 80   if (__nss_initgroups_database == NULL)
 81     {
 82       if (__nss_database_lookup2 ("initgroups", NULL, "",
 83   &__nss_initgroups_database) < 0)
 84 {
 85   if (__nss_group_database == NULL)
 86     no_more = __nss_database_lookup2 ("group", NULL, DEFAULT_CONFIG,
 87       &__nss_group_database);
 88
 89   __nss_initgroups_database = __nss_group_database;
 90 }
 91       else
 92 use_initgroups_entry = true;
 93     }
...
133       /* For compatibility reason we will continue to look for more
134    entries using the next service even though data has already
135    been found if the nsswitch.conf file contained only a 'groups'
136    line and no 'initgroups' line.  If the latter is available
137    we always respect the status.  This means that the default
138    for successful lookups is to return.  */
139       if ((use_initgroups_entry || status != NSS_STATUS_SUCCESS)
140     && nss_next_action (nip, status) == NSS_ACTION_RETURN)
141    break;
142
143       if (nip->next == NULL)
144   no_more = -1;
145       else
146   nip = nip->next;
147     }
```

It looks like it should honor the `initgroups` config, but it doesn't seem to. I tried removing the `group:` completely from nsswitch.conf but no luck. `id` command for local user still hangs

Any way to bypass this ?

In my case, if the remote directory ports are blocked or remote directory is slow to respond, the service doing the lookup goes for total hang. Our product ships with default nsswitch.conf and is not configurable by end user.

And the local user is also unable to login due to group lookup going to this remote lookup service

Comment: I made some progress on this. With a `gdb` it seems that even with a valid username and gid which exists in `passwd` and `group` file,  the `_nss_files_initgroups_dyn` function return `NSS_STATUS_NOTFOUND`. That is why it tries to go to more databases

Comment: Ok, digging more into the code for `_nss_files_initgroups_dyn`, I found the reason. The relevant code snippet is `95       if (res > 0 && grp.gr_gid != group)` So basically, the `/etc/group` file is parsed and it tries to match the user with each group member. If found, it will return success only if that group is not the user's primary group :(  Which boils down to `if user is not part of any secondary group, the group lookup will always go to other databases`

Comment: You did good job with the investigation until yov found your answer. Could you please write an "official" answer for yourself and accept it? You'll improve your reputation, while also helping other people that might have the same question in the future.

Comment: Well, till now I have just found the root cause :) The answer on how to achieve this is still eluding me ;) I have posted this query on libc mailing list [now](https://sourceware.org/pipermail/libc-help/2022-February/006113.html)